# OpenCV feature detection for recognition of multiple different images

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

My question is - can I recognize *different* templates in a source image using feature detection in OpenCV? Let's say my templates are road signs.

I am using ORB, but this is *not* tracker-specific question.

My basic approach without feature detection is:

- Image preparation (filtering etc);
- Detecting ROI where my object may be located;
- Resizing ROI to templates' size and comparing with each template I have (ie. template matching);
- Maximum correlation after comparison is an object I look for.

But with feature detection I detect keypoints and descriptors for each image in my template set and for my ROI where object might be located, but matcher returns distances for all descriptors I have in my ROI.

I can't tie this to any correlation between ROI and templates, or, in other words, I can't decide whether ROI image and template image are the same objects based on information provided by matcher.

So, to be more specific - is my approach wrong and feature detectors are used to detect *one* template object in a source image (which is not what I need) or I'm just not grasping the basic concepts of feature detection and thus am in need of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be missing two aspects. One is to remove outliers in your feature matching using a method like RANSAC+homography. The second point is to project the corners of your template to the scene, to make a "rectangle" of your image. Also you should define a threshold on how many inliers you will consider the minimum for a right detection.

Check this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography) on finding objects with feature detection.

Answer (score 0):

I will refer you to a book called:
'opencv2 computer vision application programming cookbook'

Just browse the relevant chapters.